# Showing that a series converges locally uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis

We've been given the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{n}$; I showed that it converges for $z\notin\mathbb{N}$ using the Cauchy condensation test.

The question further asks us to show that the convergence is in fact uniform on any compact set that doesn't intersect $\mathbb{N}$. Now we've shown on a previous assignment that a sequence converges locally uniformly in some open set $G$ iff it converges uniformly on each compact subset of $G$, so the question is reduced to showing that the partial sums are uniformly Cauchy on an $\epsilon$ ball around a given $z_0$. This, I can't seem to do however, because the best bound I've come up with (after obvious manipulations) looks like $$|S_{n}-S_{m}|=\frac{(n-m)}{m|w-m|},$$ for $w$ in the ball, which I can certainly blow up by choosing an $n$ large enough.

Have I gone about this question the right way? Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$th term of the series is 
$\frac{z}{n(z-n)}$. When $z$ is restricted to a bounded set that stays away from positive integers, the inequality
$$\left|\frac{z}{n(z-n)}\right|\le \frac{C}{n^2}$$
holds with $C$ independent of $n$. Consequently, the Weierstrass $M$-test applies.

Comment: This is perfect - thanks!